# How to change button image on click?

Tags: javascript, html, button, pressed

I am using images and hrefs to create buttons. Code look like this:

```
<a href="http://www.zive.sk"><img src="res/images/zive.png" alt="Zive.sk" id="ziveCircle"></a>
```

Is there any way to change image src if user press button? Maybe some event handler which will determine that user has pressed image? It should act as normal button so when user press it and keep pressed it should change image src and when he releases the button then the href should be loaded (normal button behaviour).

**PS:** I cannot use css for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, using some of Hope I Helped script. Here is the code:

```
function buttons(){
document.getElementById('zive-anchor').onmousedown=function () {
    document.getElementById('ziveCircle').src = 
    "res/images/zivePressed.png";
};
document.getElementById('zive-anchor').onmouseout=function () {
    document.getElementById('ziveCircle').src = 
    "res/images/zive.png";
};
};
```

and here is HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="homepage">
        <div id="selectCircle">
            <a href="feeds.html#page1" rel="external" id="zive-anchor"><img src="res/images/zive.png" alt="Zive.sk" id="ziveCircle"></a>
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using CSS for this?

Comment: yes, I have my images aligned using css and it is not working when I have tried putting background ("res/images/zive.pnh");. But it dint work, no image was showing at all and I am 100% sure that image path is correct

Answer (score 1):

This will change the button's image to your StackOverflow gravatar icon (change the URL accordingly):

**HTML**:

```
<a id="zive-anchor" href="javascript:void(0);">
    <img id="zive-img" src="res/images/zive.png" alt="Zive.sk" id="ziveCircle">
</a>​
```

**Javascript**:

```
document.getElementById('zive-anchor').onclick=function () {
    document.getElementById('zive-img').src = 
    "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ca2a5b453d7e221f50929cbf6d688e59?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG";
};​
```

**JSFiddle**:

http://jsfiddle.net/CsCSC/

Comment: well it is working but it isnt what I wanted. Because I want to keep my href to page http://www.zive.sk and when user stop pressing button it should change back to its normal image. I want it to look like this http://img.usabilitypost.com/0812/active_button/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

```
function play()
{



var player= document.getElementById("audio");


if(player.paused)

player.play();


else
player.pause(); 

change();

}

function change()
{

var imag = document.getElementById("play")

if(imag.src.match('Play'))
imag.src="pause.jpg";

else
imag.src="Play.jpg";



}
```