# Content of <script> printed instead of executed

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

Basically, I would like to know what could cause the content of a `<script>` tag to be printed instead of executed in HTML.

Context: I have accordion buttons, what I want to do is change the image in the button from a down arrow to an up arrow on click. I am using part of the code described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516933/how-to-change-button-image-on-click).
 If i put my code in a [fiddle, like this one](https://jsfiddle.net/gugct13w/) (I replaced img with alts to avoid local files problems), it works.

However, in my code, if I put the script before the button, nothing happens, and if i put it after it, then the content of the script apears below the button when I click it (event if it's just var a = null, then it would print var a = null).

```
<button class="accordion" id="button_emotion">VIEWS<img id="button_emotion_img" src="images/arrow_grey.svg" width="30" height="30" alt="" style="float:right;margin:0 0px 0 0px;" /></button>
<script>
    document.getElementById('button_emotion').onclick=function () {
                document.getElementById('button_emotion_img').src = "images/arrow_grey_up.svg";
    };
</script>
```

I have also tried using `onClick="myFunction()"` in the button tag with the same result.

[image]

What could be causing this?

UPDATE:

I have found the culprit. Later in the code, there is something like that:

```
<script>
        var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
                acc[i].onclick = function(){
                        this.classList.toggle("active");
                        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
                }
        }
</script>
```

I am not exactly sure what it does as I did not write this code, but it shows the next tags that are non "accordion" class. There is a modified bootstrap that makes it possible to print the content, however without it, it just doesn't execute the script, but does not print it either.

Here's the [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gugct13w/3/) with the extra code. If you put the image changing part before the script or in a `<script>` in the HTML part, it doesn't execute it (and with the modified css would print it instead), but if you place it before, the code will execute.

Comment: which browser does this happen in? that's the oddest thing I've ever seen - if you could make a fiddle where this actually happens, that'd be great - for instance - moving your code in your fiddle like https://jsfiddle.net/gugct13w/2/ doesn't display the script content

Comment: — Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @JamesDonnelly No, it doesn't, the /> part belongs to the <img> tag contained within the button.

Comment: @MorganFR oops, completely missed that `img`. I've deleted my comment.

Comment: @Rayon Yes, I am trying to make something that will produce the same result. There is a lot of code, and most of it is sensitive information. I will update as soon as I can manage that. In the meantime, any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: without knowing the rest of your scripts I don't think it's possible to figure out what causes this. this part of your code seems to be ok and that's why it works in the fiddle. if you put your script before your button, then `getElementById()` returns nothing and therefore can't apply the `onclick` handler and nothing happens on click. btw I would suggest you to use an icon font (like https://fortawesome.com/), so you can simply switch a class to toggle the arrow. or if it has to be images, use a sprite as background image and toggle a css class that modifies `background-position`.

Comment: Rather than littering the html with javascript, you'd be well advised to listen for the `load` event of the window. Once received, all of you dom has been parsed and exists - ready for interaction. Placing the code before the button means the code tried to run before the button existed. E.g `window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded); function onDocLoaded(evt){ // do all of your initialization stuff in here}`

Answer (score 0):

Setting `display` CSS property of a `<script>` tag may result in its content being printed. That was the case for me.